# EF Core - How to self reference a model with one to many relationship?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I am trying to develop a basic Referral System with ASP.NET Core Identity, where a user can be referred by another user and can also refer to users.

MemberUser entity:

```
public class MemberUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string? ReferrerId { get; set; }
    public virtual MemberUser Referrer { get; set; }
    public virtual List<MemberUser> Referrals { get; set; }

}
```

DBContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.Entity<MemberUser>()
        .HasOne(mu => mu.Referrer)
        .WithMany(mu => mu.Referrals)
        .HasForeignKey(mu => mu.ReferrerId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

}
```

When I ran dotnet ef database update it produces an error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_AspNetUsers_AspNetUsers_ReferrerId' on table 'AspNetUsers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetRoles",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetUsers",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                FirstName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(100)", maxLength: 100, nullable: false),
                LastName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(100)", maxLength: 100, nullable: false),
                ReferrerId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                UserName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                Email = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "datetimeoffset", nullable: true),
                LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUsers", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AspNetUsers_AspNetUsers_ReferrerId",
                    column: x => x.ReferrerId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id");
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetRoleClaims",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                RoleId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                ClaimType = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoleClaims", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                    column: x => x.RoleId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetUserClaims",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                ClaimType = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserClaims", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AspNetUserClaims_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetUserLogins",
            columns: table => new
            {
                LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(128)", maxLength: 128, nullable: false),
                ProviderKey = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(128)", maxLength: 128, nullable: false),
                ProviderDisplayName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserLogins", x => new { x.LoginProvider, x.ProviderKey });
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetUserRoles",
            columns: table => new
            {
                UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                RoleId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserRoles", x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                    column: x => x.RoleId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetUserTokens",
            columns: table => new
            {
                UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(128)", maxLength: 128, nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(128)", maxLength: 128, nullable: false),
                Value = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserTokens", x => new { x.UserId, x.LoginProvider, x.Name });
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AspNetUserTokens_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_AspNetRoleClaims_RoleId",
            table: "AspNetRoleClaims",
            column: "RoleId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "RoleNameIndex",
            table: "AspNetRoles",
            column: "NormalizedName",
            unique: true,
            filter: "[NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_AspNetUserClaims_UserId",
            table: "AspNetUserClaims",
            column: "UserId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_AspNetUserLogins_UserId",
            table: "AspNetUserLogins",
            column: "UserId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_AspNetUserRoles_RoleId",
            table: "AspNetUserRoles",
            column: "RoleId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "EmailIndex",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            column: "NormalizedEmail");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_AspNetUsers_ReferrerId",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            column: "ReferrerId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "UserNameIndex",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            column: "NormalizedUserName",
            unique: true,
            filter: "[NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "AspNetRoleClaims");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "AspNetUserClaims");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "AspNetUserLogins");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "AspNetUserRoles");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "AspNetUserTokens");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "AspNetRoles");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "AspNetUsers");
    }
}
```

Comment: Before running `database update` remove the current migration and then run another `migrations add` command. And show us your generated migration file if it is still not working.

Comment: I have added the migration output

Comment: What I meant was the content of the migration file.

Comment: oh i'm sorry i have included the migration file now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually fix your migration file by modifying the relationship like below :

```
 constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUsers", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AspNetUsers_AspNetUsers_ReferrerId",
                    column: x => x.ReferrerId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);
            });
```

Or you can remove this migration and add another that includes the correct `onDelete` action as I mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I have applied your solution and it worked!, but now I have changed my mind,  I want to set the foreign key to null if the dependent user is deleted. I change it to `ReferentialAction.SetNull` but it produces the same error.

Comment: @zvz this is some kind of limitation that's why EF complains about it. Think of a scenario where you want to delete a user which has cycles of `ReferrerId` in the end somehow that refers to itself. EF will fail to decide the correct order of what to delete first. It will fail at least if it did not crash your program already.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand now. I have thought of getting all the users who are reffered to the user I want to delete and unset all their `ReferrerId` column before deleting the user. Is that okay?

Comment: @zvz yeap that should work.